# How to get the QWebFrame for an iframe/frame QWebElement?

Tags: qt, iframe, qtwebkit

I have simple Qt GUI application which uses QtWebkit. I am loading complex page with a lot of nested IFRAME-tags. And I want to traverse complete DOM tree (like Chrome browser does in debug-panel) including content of iframes.

My code is:

```
QWebElement doc = ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->documentElement();
QWebElement iframe = doc.findFirst("iframe[id=someid]");
QWebFrame *webFrame = ....? // how to get the QWebFrame for an iframe/frame QWebElement?
```

Note:
I can traverse over all frames (including nested):

```
void MainWindow::renderFramesTree(QWebFrame *frame, int indent)
{
    QString s;
    s.fill(' ', indent * 4);
    ui->textLog->appendPlainText(s + " " + frame->frameName());
    foreach (QWebFrame *child, frame->childFrames())
        renderFramesTree(child, indent + 1);
}
```

But my question is not about that. I need to get corresponding QWebFrame* of iframe-QWebElement.

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

Each QWebFrame has `QList<QWebFrame *> QWebFrame::childFrames () const` method. Each frame has also `QString QWebFrame::frameName () const`. Combining both may let you find what you need.

```
QWebFrame * frameImLookingFor = NULL;
foreach(QWebFrame * frame, ui->webView->page()->mainFrame()->childFrames())
{
    if (frame->frameName() == QLatin1String("appFrame"))
    {
        frameImLookingFor = frame;
        break;
    }
}

if (frameImLookingFor)
{
    // do what you need
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is good solution but only if you know name or id of <iframe> tag. Point of quesin is how to get QWebFrame which is loaded by taken iframe-QWebElement

Comment: I used 3 factors for this: name or id, geometry and source URL. You can compare geometry from frame and webelement, src attribute and URL from frame. But even so, in some rare cases I wasn't able to match frames tree to iframe nodes, but very unfrequently

Answer (score 0):

- run selector on current frame
- if it returns something that's good we found that our webframe is on the current frame, lets call this element X :

  - now get all frame elements using selector "iframe,frame" from current page
  - loop trough all those elements and try to match them with X frame
    this way you'll be able to find exact INDEX of the X frame in document
  - finally you are now able to focus on child frame with that INDEX
- else this means that selector is not found in this frame

  - loop trough all child frames and repeat the whole process for each child frame